# C program terminates unexpectedly

Tags: c, encryption

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void encrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
        {
            cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] + shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
        }
    }
}

void decrypting(char cipher[25], int shift, int num)
{
    inti;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (cipher[i] >= 'A' && cipher[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'A' + 26) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        else if (cipher[i] >= 'a' && cipher[i] <= 'z')
        {
            cipher[i] = (char)(((cipher[i] - shift - 'a' + 26) % 26) + 'a');
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char text[10];
    static const char encrypt[] = "2";
    static const char decrypt[] = "1";
    int shift;
    char cipher[25];
    int result1;
    int result2;
    int num;
    int i;



    printf("Enter operation: encrypt or decrypt/n");
    printf("Press 1 to Encrypt or 2 to Decrypt");
    scanf("%c", &text);
    printf("Enter shift key");
    scanf("%d", &shift);
    printf("Enter text to encrypt/decrypt");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &cipher);

    num = strlen(cipher);

    result1 = strcmp(text, encrypt);
    result2 = strcmp(text, decrypt);

    if (result1 == 0)
    {
        decrypting(cipher, shift, num);
    }
    else { exit(0); }

    if (result2 == 0)
    {
        encrypting(cipher, shift, num);
    }
    else { exit(0); }

    printf("Result");
    printf("%d", cipher);
}
```

The program terminates unexpectedly after the user input the text for cipher. I have no idea whats the problem right now. Could anyone explain whats the problem with my code right now? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code systematically and avoid tabs as the indentation character, at least for code posted on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling `exit(0);` before `printf("Result");` no matter whether the user wanted to encrypt or decrypt. Change:

```
else{exit(0);}

if(result2 == 0)
```

To:

```
else if(result2 == 0)
```

Then it'll only call `exit(0);` if they chose neither encryption nor decryption.

---

Also, `printf("%d",cipher);` won't work to print a string. You need to use the `%s` conversion specifier rather than `%d`.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion and now the output is numbers, instead of characters

Comment: @user1852728: You also need to change the `%d` conversion specifier to `%s` in the `printf`; otherwise, it tries to print a `d`ecimal number rather than a `s`tring.

Comment: I've changed  printf("%d",cipher); to   printf("%s",cipher);
the encryption/decryption now only work on the first character.

Comment: I correected my code, IO've changed     scanf( "%c",&cipher) ;
to     scanf( "%s",&cipher) ; and my code now works

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` conversion specifier in the format string of `scanf` does not discard the leading whitespace characters. This means that the newline character `'\n'` will be left in the buffer after the following `scanf` call -

```
scanf("%d", &shift);
```

This newline will be read in the next `scanf` call -

```
scanf("%c", &cipher);
```

That's because it's undefined behaviour to call `fflush` on an input stream. It's defined only for output streams. This means the following statement is wrong -

```
fflush(stdin);
```

I suggest you to use `fgets` to read an input string and then extract the character from the string. Also, output a newline to print the message on the screen immediately.

Comment: Note that Microsoft defines the behaviour of `fflush(stdin);`, even though the C standard does not.

Comment: Yes, even the man page of `fflush` on my system(Ubuntu 14.04) says - `For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by  the  application. The open status of the stream is unaffected.` But I have read that it's not portable.